# Camel hdfs2 to file protocol files transfer

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-camel

I want to copy files from `hdfs` file system to local `file` system. I tried a simple route in Java DSL.

```
from("hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user?owner=honey")
        .to("file:/home/honey/Desktop/DATA");
```

But its not working. These are the logs.

```
2014-11-13 22:16:22,169 DEBUG [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user] util.Shell (Shell.java:326) - setsid exited with exit code 0
2014-11-13 22:16:22,186 DEBUG [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user] hdfs2.HdfsConsumer (HdfsConsumer.java:87) - Connected to hdfs file-system 192.168.1.55:9000/hdfs://192.168.1.55:9000/user
2014-11-13 22:16:22,189 INFO  [main] hdfs2.HdfsConsumer (HdfsConsumer.java:84) - Connected to hdfs file-system 192.168.1.55:9000/hdfs://192.168.1.55:9000/user
2014-11-13 22:16:22,189 INFO  [main] impl.DefaultCamelContext (DefaultCamelContext.java:2310) - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user?owner=honey]
2014-11-13 22:16:22,190 DEBUG [main] management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy$TimerListenerManagerStartupListener (DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy.java:893) - Load performance statistics disabled
2014-11-13 22:16:22,190 INFO  [main] impl.DefaultCamelContext (DefaultCamelContext.java:1654) - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
2014-11-13 22:16:22,192 INFO  [main] impl.DefaultCamelContext (DefaultCamelContext.java:1655) - Apache Camel 2.13.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.521 seconds
2014-11-13 22:16:22,202 DEBUG [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user] ipc.Client$Connection (Client.java:371) - The ping interval is 60000 ms.
2014-11-13 22:16:22,204 DEBUG [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user] ipc.Client$Connection (Client.java:636) - Connecting to /192.168.1.55:9000
2014-11-13 22:16:22,218 DEBUG [IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey] ipc.Client$Connection (Client.java:886) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey: starting, having connections 1
2014-11-13 22:16:22,220 DEBUG [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0] ipc.Client$Connection$3 (Client.java:948) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey sending #0
2014-11-13 22:16:22,227 DEBUG [IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey] ipc.Client$Connection (Client.java:1005) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey got value #0
2014-11-13 22:16:22,227 DEBUG [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user] ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker (ProtobufRpcEngine.java:221) - Call: getFileInfo took 36ms
2014-11-13 22:16:22,253 DEBUG [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0] ipc.Client$Connection$3 (Client.java:948) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey sending #1
2014-11-13 22:16:22,255 DEBUG [IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey] ipc.Client$Connection (Client.java:1005) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey got value #1
2014-11-13 22:16:22,255 DEBUG [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user] ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker (ProtobufRpcEngine.java:221) - Call: getFileInfo took 2ms
2014-11-13 22:16:22,256 DEBUG [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0] ipc.Client$Connection$3 (Client.java:948) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey sending #2
2014-11-13 22:16:22,257 DEBUG [IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey] ipc.Client$Connection (Client.java:1005) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey got value #2
2014-11-13 22:16:22,257 DEBUG [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - hdfs2://192.168.1.55:9000/user] ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker (ProtobufRpcEngine.java:221) - Call: getFileInfo took 1ms
2014-11-13 22:16:22,259 DEBUG [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0] ipc.Client$Connection$3 (Client.java:948) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey sending #3
2014-11-13 22:16:22,261 DEBUG [IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey] ipc.Client$Connection (Client.java:1005) - IPC Client (1506043150) connection to /192.168.1.55:9000 from honey got value #3
so on.....
```

In these below logs are repeating continuously. But same thing if i try to copy files from local `file system` to `hdfs` then its working flawlessly. Can anyone provide me any working link or example? It would be very helpful.

**Edit:**
Now it worked for me. `readSuffix was read by default` , it won't read again those file which already had been read. Now my Question is why is there any `recursive option in consumer side.` I want to consume files in a recursive manner. Like we can scan in `File2` using recursive option.

Comment: @claus-ibsen Do you wanna tell something here? :P
your help would be very appreciable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation and the source code of Camel's HDFS2 component, I guess that this is not possible.

You could open a CR for this issue. Or even better, implement this on your own (first having a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java#FsShell.ls%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29) to see how to recursively scan a directory in HDFS) and make a gift to the Apache foundation...

Comment: Thanks Peter..I will try to implement it in free time. Thanks anyways :)